# What is wrong with my ssmtp.conf file?

Tags: configuration, ssmtp

I can send email from my terminal through gmail with my ssmtp.conf file as it is below, but I think it's not right:

```
root=me@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
hostname=MyComputerName
UseTLS=YES
#UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=me@gmail.com
AuthPass=password
FromLineOverride=YES
```

If I put "me@gmail.com" as hostname instead of my computer name, I can't send.

If I uncomment "UseSTARTTLS=YES", I can't send.

Some configuration file examples show using port 587, but if I try that, I can't send.

I'm trying to understand what's wrong.

Some ssmtp.conf examples I found online using TLS don't include any SSL certificate, so I'm guessing I don't need one.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: No, I left the problem waiting for someone who might know what's wrong. It sends, but the main problem is I don't know if I'm really sending TLS or not.